# jQuery left right keyboard shortcut to visit through pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination, keyboard-shortcuts

So I was trying to bind the left - right keyboard arrow keys to navigate through pagination in website.

This is my HTML.

```
<div class="page-nav">
  <a href="page1.html" class="prev">&lt;- Previous</a>
  <a href="page3.html" class="next">Next -&gt;</a>
</div>
```

And this is jQuery

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 37:
      $(".prev" ).click();
      break;

    case 39:
      $( ".next" ).click();
      break;

    default: return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

But I am not sure why it's not working. It's suppose to click button on key stroke. Although when I log event for each then it's detecting key strokes but not visiting pages.

EDIT: And also how to check if there is a prev button to go to. Then it must go. Otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is working.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var prevPageLink = $( ".prev" ).attr('href');
  var nextPageLink = $( ".next" ).attr('href');
  switch(e.which) {
    case 37:
      if ( prevPageLink ) {
        window.location = prevPageLink;
      }
      break;

    case 39:
      if ( nextPageLink ) {
        window.location = nextPageLink;
      }
      break;

    default: return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

If someone has better method, let me know. :)